# Why does a line integral not depend on the parametrization you use?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I have a question about my calculus course:

Why is it true that a line integral over a certain functiondoes not depend on the parametrization you use?. For example, take a function $f(x,y,z)$ of 3 variables

Comment: If line integrals are included in your course, the proof of this fact should be in your textbook (immediately after the definition of line integrals, presumably)...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is best understood by recognizing that a line integral is no different than your classic 1D integral. The only difference is that instead of considering the area under the function over the path $x\in [a,b]$, you have to consider the area under the function over the path $C$ - a curve.

How do you parametrize a 1D path? Personally, I would do it as $C = a+t(b-a)$ for $t\in [0,1]$. However, you could just as easily do it as $C= a + 2t(b-a)$ for $t\in [0,1/2]$. Regardless of how you describe your path, the area underneath that path is the same. Perform both of these 1D integrals yourself if you still need convincing.

Going back to a line integral with a path through space, we have the same conclusion. It doesn't matter how you describe the path. As long as you are describing the same path, the area under that curve along the path remains the same. Therefore, the line integral does not depend on the specific parametrization you are using.